# Por que por "new Array()" após a variável?

Tags: javascript, array, orientação-a-objetos, declaração-de-variável

Por que colocar `new Array()` após o nome da variável?
Exemplo:

```
var weatherPattern = new Array('Clouds', "raining", "clowdy");
```

Comment: Por que não colocar? Qual o objetivo da pergunta? Dê mais detalhes, contexto do que quer saber. Está querendo comparar com alguma outra forma?

Comment: Eu vejo uns exemplo em que a pessoa cria um array e antes do array coloca esse ``new Array``, queria saber se ha alguma significado ou colocam por colocar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esta é uma forma de declarar um *array*  em JavaScript, você chama uma função `Array()` que deve justamente gerar o *array* para atribuir à variável. O `new` é usado para indicar a alocação do objeto. Não tem segredo algum, é igual a outros objetos não primitivos.

Existe a sintaxe onde o *array* é criado como um literal na linguagem. O efeito é o mesmo e fica mais conciso e até mais legível.

Neste exemplo não vejo porque não usar o literal, como mostrado abaixo, o efeito é o mesmo, então se usaram assim deve ser questão de estilo. Fora isto teria que perguntar para quem fez, porque tecnicamente é a mesma coisa.

```js
var weatherPattern = new Array('Clouds', "raining", "clowdy");
var weatherPattern = ['Clouds', "raining", "clowdy")];
```

Em alguns interpretadores de JS pode ser que um funcione mais rápido que outro, mas isso não é garantido sempre.

Porém os seguintes são diferentes:

```js
var weatherPattern = new Array(5);
var weatherPattern = [5];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/LiteralVsType.js).

O primeiro cria um *array* e reserva 5 posições para alocar objetos, o segundo cria um *array* com um elemento numérico que vale 5, são coisas bem distintas. Neste caso o argumento passado para a função `Array()` não se comporta como um elemento do *array* e sim como um parâmetro de configuração do tamanho do *array*.

Tem mais um pegadinha. A função `Array()` pode fazer algo diferente do que se espera já que JS permite que ela seja sobrescrita. Pode ser que sequer ela crie um *array*. Claro que nenhum programador deveria fazer isso, mas pode. O que não deixa de ser um possível truque interessante.

JavaScript tem essas esquisitices mesmo.